# Calculate the number of unordered pairs in an array whose bitwise "AND" is a power of 2 in O(n) or O(n*log(n))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation, bitmask

How to calculate number of unordered pairs in an array whose bitwise **AND** is a power of `2`. For ex if the array is `[10,7,2,8,3]`. The answer is `6`. 
Explanation(0-based index):

- `a[0]&a[1] = 2`
- `a[0]&a[2] = 2`
- `a[0]&a[3] = 8`
- `a[0]&a[4] = 2`
- `a[1]&a[2] = 2`
- `a[2]&a[4] = 2`

The only approach that comes to my mind is brute force. How to optimize it to perform in **O(n)** or **O(n*log(n))**?

The constraints on the size of array can be at max `10^5`. And the value in that array can be upto `10^12`.

Here is the brute force code that I tried.

```java
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            long and = a[i] & a[j];
            if ((and & (and - 1)) == 0 && and != 0)
                ans++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: Suppose there are *m* values which are not a power of 2.  There are then _m*(m+1)/2_ unordered pairs of values which when ANDed together are not a power of 2.

Comment: @ChrisHall 6 and 3 are not powers of two. According to your statement there are then 2 * 3 / 2 = 3 unordered pairs which when ANDed together are not powers of 2. But for input, [6, 3], there are zero such unordered pairs, and one pair that when ANDed together are a power of 2. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @גלעדברקן  -- ah, brain fade.. *power* of 2 not *multiple* of 2 :-(   Sorry.  OK. So we're looking for unordered pairs which have exactly 1 bit in common.  More thought required.

Comment: What are the bounds on the values in `a`?

Comment: Since there might be O(n<sup>2</sup>) such unordered pairs, it will be difficult to generate them in less time, but if you just want to calucate how many exist, it might be possible.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Just counting such pairs is only required.

Comment: Do you want a *practical* best answer or a *theoretical* best answer?  Because I pretty sure I know a solution that is `O(n)` as long as you ignore word-size issues, but it is extremely impractical.  Also, for a problem like this, you really should evaluate it in terms of the total bit-length of the input, rather than just the number of inputs.

Comment: It can definitely be done in `O(n+2^m)` where `m` is the length of the bit-mask.  But that's very likely to be highly impractical.

Comment: @RBarryYoung please post your `O(n+2^m)` solution.

Comment: @RBarryYoung also the `O(n)` solution. They sound very interesting.

Comment: @RBarryYoung OP provided both the number of expected elements and their range. What seems missing to you in the constraints?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Also, I'm still trying to figure out if your solution is effectively the same as mine.

Comment: oops, rather, my `O(n+2^m)` solution is the `O(n)` solution that I was thinking of.  I am hesitant to post it because `10^12 = 2^40` approximately, so my solution would require at least 4^40 steps (and that much memory).  Way too impractical.  My approach would only be practical when `n^2 >> 4^m` which is nowhere close in this case.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'd still be interested in O(n + 2^m) since mine has an additional m^2 factor -- O(2^N * N^2 + n * N) complexity, where N is the number of bits in the range. So getting rid of the extra m^2 factor would be very interesting.

Comment: Can you share your solution in java in an answer to help others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this answer is for a smaller range constraint (possibly suited up to about 2^20), I thought I'd add it since it may add some useful information.

We can adapt the [bit-subset dynamic programming idea](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/45223) to have a solution with `O(2^N * N^2 + n * N)` complexity, where `N` is the number of bits in the range, and `n` is the number of elements in the list. (So if the integers were restricted to [1, 1048576] or 2^20, with `n` at 100,000, we would have on the order of 2^20 * 20^2 + 100000*20 = 421,430,400 iterations.)

The idea is that we want to count instances for which we have overlapping bit subsets, with the twist of adding a fixed set bit. Given `Ai` -- for simplicity, take `6 = b110` -- if we were to find all partners that AND to zero, we'd take `Ai`'s negation,

```
110 -> ~110 -> 001
```

Now we can build a dynamic program that takes a diminishing mask, starting with the full number and diminishing the mask towards the left

```
001
^^^

001
^^

001
^
```

Each set bit on the negation of `Ai` represents a zero, which can be ANDed with either 1 or 0 to the same effect. Each unset bit on the negation of `Ai` represents a set bit in `Ai`, which we'd like to pair only with zeros, *except for a single set bit*.

We construct this set bit by examining each possibility separately. So where to count pairs that would AND with `Ai` to zero, we'd do something like

```
001 ->
  001
  000
```

we now want to enumerate

```
011 ->
  011
  010

101 ->
  101
  100
```

fixing a single bit each time.

We can achieve this by adding a dimension to the inner iteration. When the mask does have a set bit at the end, we "fix" the relevant bit by counting only the result for the previous DP cell that would have the bit set, and not the usual union of subsets that could either have that bit set or not.

Here is some JavaScript code to demonstrate with testing at the end comparing to the brute-force solution.

```js
var debug = 0;

function bruteForce(a){
  let answer = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      let and = a[i] & a[j];
      if ((and & (and - 1)) == 0 && and != 0){
        answer++;
        if (debug)
          console.log(a[i], a[j], a[i].toString(2), a[j].toString(2))
      }
    }
  }
  return answer;
}
  
function f(A, N){
  const n = A.length;
  const hash = {}; 
  const dp = new Array(1 << N);
  
  for (let i=0; i<1<<N; i++){
    dp[i] = new Array(N + 1);
    
    for (let j=0; j<N+1; j++)
      dp[i][j] = new Array(N + 1).fill(0);
  }
      
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(A[i]))
      hash[A[i]] = hash[A[i]] + 1;
    else
      hash[A[i]] = 1;
  }
  
  for (let mask=0; mask<1<<N; mask++){
    // j is an index where we fix a 1
    for (let j=0; j<=N; j++){
      if (mask & 1){
        if (j == 0)
          dp[mask][j][0] = hash[mask] || 0;
        else
          dp[mask][j][0] = (hash[mask] || 0) + (hash[mask ^ 1] || 0);
        
      } else {
        dp[mask][j][0] = hash[mask] || 0;
      }
    
      for (let i=1; i<=N; i++){
        if (mask & (1 << i)){
          if (j == i)
            dp[mask][j][i] = dp[mask][j][i-1];
          else
            dp[mask][j][i] = dp[mask][j][i-1] + dp[mask ^ (1 << i)][j][i - 1];
          
        } else {
          dp[mask][j][i] = dp[mask][j][i-1];
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  
  let answer = 0; 
  
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<N; j++)
      if (A[i] & (1 << j))
        answer += dp[((1 << N) - 1) ^ A[i] | (1 << j)][j][N];
  }

  for (let i=0; i<N + 1; i++)
    if (hash[1 << i])
      answer = answer - hash[1 << i];

  return answer / 2;
} 
 
var As = [
  [5, 4, 1, 6], // 4
  [10, 7, 2, 8, 3], // 6
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];

for (let A of As){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
  console.log(`DP, brute force: ${ f(A, 4) }, ${ bruteForce(A) }`);
  console.log('');
}

var numTests = 1000;

for (let i=0; i<numTests; i++){
  const N = 6;
  const A = [];
  const n = 10;
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++){
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 << N));
    A.push(num);
  }

  const fA = f(A, N);
  const brute = bruteForce(A);
  
  if (fA != brute){
    console.log('Mismatch:');
    console.log(A);
    console.log(fA, brute);
    console.log('');
  }
}

console.log("Done testing.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform your array of values into an array of index sets, where each set corresponds to a particular bit and contains the indexes of the value from the original set that have the bit set.  For example, your example array A = `[10,7,2,8,3]` becomes B = `[{1,4}, {0,1,2,4}, {1}, {0,3}]`.  A fixed-sized array of bitvectors is an ideal data structure for this, as it makes set union/intersection/setminus relatively easy and efficient.

Once you have that array of sets B (takes O(nm) time where `m` is the size of your integers in bits), iterate over every element *i* of A again, computing ∑<sub>j</sub>|B<sub>j</sub>∖i∖⋃<sub>k</sub>B<sub>k</sub>:k≠j∧i∈B<sub>k</sub>|:i∈B<sub>j</sub>.  Add those all together and divide by 2, and that *should* be the number of pairs (the "divide by 2" is because this counts each pair twice, as what it is counting is the number of numbers each number pairs with).  Should only take O(nm<sup>2</sup>) assuming you count the setminus operations as O(1) -- if you count them as O(n), then you're back to O(n<sup>2</sup>), but at least your constant factor should be small if you have efficient bitsets.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach A[i] in A:
    foreach bit in A[i]:
        B[bit] += {i}

pairs = 0
foreach A[i] in A:
    foreach B[j] in B:
        if i in B[j]:
            tmp = B[j] - {i}
            foreach B[k] in B:
                if k != j && i in B[k]:
                    tmp -= B[k]
            pairs += |tmp|

return pairs/2
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldn’t understand your mathematical notation. Can you show with an example as you explained in first part of sentence basically showing what all to add together and divide by 2?

Comment: Ok, so I think I fixed it, and added pseudocode to illustrate the algorithm

Comment: @ChrisDodd: each of the sets in `B` can have size proportional to `n`. Computing subsets by `B[j] - {i}` and `tmp -= B[k]` cannot easily be achieved in O(1) time. The first because it needs to create a copy, but there might be ways to share sets and achieve this in O(1) time, and the second, `tmp -= B[k]`, seems much harder to achieve in O(1) time in the general case.

Comment: Thus my comment about the O-complexity really depending on the cost of set-minus.  However, bitvec set implementations are extremely CPU and (streaming) cache friendly, so the constant factor is likely to be at least 64x better than the OP's brute force approach.  Given the low bound of 10^5 for the array size, that is likely very important.